# AWS + Cloudflare | https getting redirected to http

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, cloudflare, aws-application-load-balancer

I have just moved a MERN Stack app to AWS and I'm currently facing some problems with the certificates.

Current Scenario:

1. My website (`example.com`) has Cloudflare as the DNS Management.
2. I have added Cloudflare's Full SSL (end-to-end) encryption and a page rule for always redirect to `https`.
3. On the AWS Side, I have an Application Load Balancer (ALB) which is having a listener for `HTTPS:443` using the certificate provided by AWS CA for `example.com`.

Problem:

1. When making a call to `example.com`, it redirects me to https://example.com and renders the static page which is fine.
2. When I change the page to https://example.com/articles the website goes berserk and changes it to http://example.com/articles and the certificate sign shows insecure now! Although, I do get my articles response from the server. Moreover, this is only happening in chrome and not firefox!

I would be more than happy to share any details/images required to support my query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please share your page rules here. Your page rules are getting problem for you.
You can use the `Always Use HTTPS` function provided without wasting your page rules.
[image]